# TeXShop: References appear as question marks

Tags: cross-referencing, texshop

When I compile my file via TeXShop on my Mac I get question marks in the place of references. I don't believe that this is an issue with my script, as the document compiles just fine when using TexStudio with proper references from my bibtex file.

I have read some of the other questions regarding this issue, and I believe that my settings are correct. Under the "Typesetting" tab of the preferences, the default command is "LaTeX" and the default script is "Pdftex". Is there an option that I am missing here?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you run the normal cycle `(pdf)latex -> bibtex/biber -> (pdf)latex (twice)`?

Comment: You can use the `pdflatexmk` Engine in TeXShop to mimic the behaviour you see in TeXStudio. See [all-in-one-engine for TeXShop](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/41271) for details on how to do this, and also [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/78101) for how to choose the engine on a per file basis.

Comment: @bernard Thank you for the warm welcome. I was not running the cycle you suggested it worked! However, it feels a bit archaic as I am coming from TeX Studio where this is seamless. Thank you kindly for the help.

Comment: @alanmunn Thank you for the suggestion. I will definitely look into the engine. I love how seamless TexStudio is, but the UI is a bit much. TexShop is really straightforward and their dark mode on Mac is excellent. I appreciate the help!